# Do I need to implement __hash__?

Tags: python, hash, set, hashtable, hashcode

I have this class and use it in the manner shown in `__main__`:

```
class User:

  def __init__(self, username, password, isActive):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.isActive = isActive

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.__dict__)

  def __eq__(self, other):
      return (isinstance(other, self.__class__)
          and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)

  def __ne__(self, other):
      return not self.__eq__(other)

  def __hash__(self):
    # Error here: TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
    return hash(tuple(self.username, self.password, self.isActive))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  s1 = set()
  s2 = set()

  # These two instances should be equivalent
  s1.add(User("bob", "12hhjka9#", True))
  s2.add(User("bob", "12hhjka9#", True))

  # These two instances should not be equivalent
  s1.add(User("alice", "12hhjka9#", False))
  s1.add(User("alice", "12hhjka9#", True))

  for user in s1.symmetric_difference(s2):
    print str(user)
  print "done"
```

Instances of this class are never changed after construction, so it is safe to use instance variables in the hash implementation. I get this error during execution:

```
# Error here: TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

I've tried other variations of `__hash__`, but can't get it right. Help!

Comment: If you remove the word `tuple`, you will get a tuple automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply using the `tuple()` function incorrectly; it is not even needed here.

The following will work:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.username, self.password, self.isActive))
```

The `tuple()` function can only take **one** argument, but you passed in 3. You'd pass in another iterable:

```
return hash(tuple([self.username, self.password, self.isActive]))
```

but using just parentheses (`(...)`) to group the values produces a single tuple too.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a namedtuple instead of your own custom class.  This is built in to Python's standard library.

```
from collections import namedtuple
User = namedtuple('User', ('username', 'password', 'isActive'))
```

Named tuples are subclasses of tuple, so hashes and equalities are already taken care of.